# Meaning of "in" as in "in all of its splendor / grace / glory," etc

Tags: prepositions, construction

### Background

This question is asked with regard to the final sentence from [this article](https://www.laphamsquarterly.org/communication/word-word) which discusses Peter Mark Roget's Thesaurus:

> Though we can be sure that he would have deplored the mindlessness of the word processor’s search-and-replace shortcuts, I feel equally confident that Roget would have appreciated the ways that new technologies can deepen our appreciation of the lexicon’s richness **in all of its interwoven splendor**.

### Research

I found these examples using corpus searches:

> Yet I tell you that not even Solomon **in all his splendor** was dressed like one of these.

> that word has too homely a ring to it to do justice to those stores **in all their splendor**

I feel these usages of "in" to be noteworthy. They are certainly of another sort of "in" than found in the most usual cases concerning relationship between physical objects. Comparable constructions include "in all (its) grace / glory." They act like postpositive adjectives attached to nouns, if not adverbial phrases. I think they imply a sense of comparison (between the state of "full glory" and anything that's not it) in the sentence.

### Questions

1. Am I justified in the hunches/feelings articulated above?
2. Are there any other idiomatic constructions using "in" in a similar comparative/descriptive sense, beyond "in all (of) something"?

Comment: "Solomon in all his glory/splendour" (Bible translations vary) is a reference to a famous king of Israel in his royal robes; Jesus says that, though the king must have looked very splendid, a natural flower looks even finer.

Comment: I find this _in_ to be the same as _a woman in a red dress_.